# Vuejs / Laravel route is not working in the production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

We have a vue.js SPA for the front-end and **laravel** RESTapi for the backend.

In my SPA I have an unprotected route called return

```
{
      path: '/return',
      component: returnPage
},
```

When I run the project on my local machine I can easily access this route
like this

http://localhost:8080/return

But after I build the project and host it in the server and when I try to insert this

http://emaster.lk/return

It gives me an error.

[image]

Why could this happen?
Any idea?

Comment: Surely the logfiles are the first place to look? Your Laravel log (`storage/logs/laravel.log`), your Apache logs, your PHP logs should give you details of exactly happened.

Answer (score 0):

Still can't give comments yet, so this is basically not an answer but a suggestion:

This could be a server misconfiguration, I have interacted with apache server that much but normally I will use nginx, you can checkout a sample configuration here with nginx and laravel [laravel-nginx-ss-setup](https://centric.tk/post/setup-laravel-vue-project-on-ubuntu-18-with-nginx-server-and-install-ssl-certificate)

And here is just a snapshot from the post:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

server_name domain_name.com www.domain_name.com;

access_log /var//www/html/<name-of-your-project>/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/html/<name-of-your-project>/logs/error.log;

root /var/www/html/<name-of-your-project>/public;
index index.php index.html;

# serve static files directly
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

# removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
if (!-d $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# enforce NO www
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
{
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
}

# unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; # may also be: 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}